# Diff-in-Diff: Interactions using three categorical variables

Tags: regression, interaction, difference-in-difference

I have a difference-in-difference question regarding three way interactions for three binary categorical variables, one of which is time.

In traditional three way interactions, the hierarchy principle tells us that you must include all the main effects, the first order effects, and then finally the three way effect. Intuitively, I think this only holds if the all possible permutations are allowed, and if the observations are independent of one another.

To help give some context to the question I will ask, I'll describe my situation. I have firm-level panel data which is structured such that one firm has two observations; one for t=0, and one for t=1. The classic three way DiD regression equation is:

**Y<sub>it</sub> = β<sub>1</sub>Treat + β<sub>2</sub>Time + β<sub>3</sub>Size + β<sub>4</sub>TreatTime + β<sub>5</sub>TreatSize + β<sub>6</sub>TimeSize + β<sub>7</sub>TreatTimeSize**

Treat is some treatment which was applied between t=0 and t=1, and size is firm size. Firm size is fixed to the value recorded at t=0 and is not allowed to vary.

I'm in a situation where β<sub>7</sub> is significant if I can drop one of the first order terms, but is not if I include all of them. So, I've been trying to come up with an argument to do so.

In my case, I believe that my data are not 'independent' of one another. Why? Well, since there are two observations per firm and size is not allowed to vary there is some higher order conditionality in the data (higher order meaning between entries). In additional if a firm received treatment, the label is applied to the t=0 entry for that firm (again, conditionality between entries).

Is this is sufficient argument to drop some of the first order terms, and if so which ones? Intuitively I would like to drop the **TreatTime** term because I don't understand what it is controlling for.

Thanks for any help. Responses as detailed as possible welcome!